# How to add comment header to program automatically? Code::Blocks

Tags: header, comments, codeblocks

I was using DevC++. It had a option under EDIT/INSERT/COMMENT HEADER to add comment header automatically. I switched to Code::Blocks. Does Code::Blocks  have this option? I am searching internet but could not find any info on how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Not truly related to the `C` tag, is it ?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution as part of DevC++ only, or some other solution? On which platform are you running DevC++?

Comment: You are right I deleted C tag

Comment: Code::Blocks has a similar option? I switched to Code:: Blocks for some reason. It was a handy feature of DevC++I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **Code Snippets Plugin** which is already available in default Code::Blocks installation.

> From View check "Code Snippets". Then right click to Code Snippets
>   menu and create a sub category named "Comments". Then right click to
>   "Comments" category and click to "Add Snippet". Then paste your
>   comment header and save it as "Header Comment". After that, you can
>   drag and drop your Header Comment anytime to anywhere.

Code snippets can be formed for other frequently used codes similarly.